# Facing issues with taking a picture and sending it as attachment through an email client (android app)

Tags: android, email

I am building a small Android app that lets people donate food through an email client. After taking the picture and viewing its thumbnail, when I hit submit, the Gmail app (email client) crashes. Basically, I want the user input information to be sent through email along with an image attachment from the picture taken just now.

I know am doing something wrong around the image file attachment area.
Help!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name of Company / Individual:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCompName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:hint="Ex: Chicken Hut, Kaldi's Coffee, etc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Telephone Number (required)" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPhone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Ex: 0922092161"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Describe your Location:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etLocation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:hint="Briefly describe where you are located..." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Food Type:" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFoodType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:hint="Ex: Local Food, Sandwiches, etc." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Estimated Quantity (in grams):" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etQuantity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:hint="Ex: 1kg, 50g, etc." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Snap a Picture of Food (if available)" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFood"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_weight="0.9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bCam"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="#ee9d3e"
    android:text="Open Camera"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSubmit"
    android:background="#cecbc8"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
   package com.example.android.foodshare;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
     import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;


     public class Donation extends AppCompatActivity implements 
     View.OnClickListener {

Button submit, open_cam;
EditText company_name;
EditText phone_number;
EditText location;
EditText foodType;
EditText quantity;
ImageView the_food;

String companyNameString;
String phoneNumberString;
String locationString;
String foodTypeString;
String quantityString;

String emailTo = "blablabla@gmail.com";
String emailContent;
String emailSubject;

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
Bitmap imageBitmap;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donation);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
    open_cam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCam);
    the_food = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivFood);
    company_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCompName);
    phone_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLocation);
    foodType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFoodType);
    quantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    open_cam.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bCam:


                Intent takePictureIntent = new 
         Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) 
          != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 
           REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            break;

        case R.id.bSubmit:
            companyNameString = company_name.getText().toString();
            phoneNumberString = phone_number.getText().toString();
            locationString = location.getText().toString();
            foodTypeString = foodType.getText().toString();
            quantityString = quantity.getText().toString();

            emailContent = "You have received a Food Pickup Request. Please 
           find further details below:\n\n" +
                    "Name of Organization (or Individual): " + 
            companyNameString + "\n" +
                    "Telephone Number: " + phoneNumberString + "\n" +
                    "Location: " + locationString + "\n" +
                    "Available Food Type: " + foodTypeString + "\n" +
                    "Quantity Available: " + quantityString;

            emailSubject = "New Food Pickup Request From " + 
            companyNameString; // maybe add from which company

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailTo});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailContent);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageBitmap);

            //need this to prompts email client only
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send 
            mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Donation.this, "There are no email clients 
            installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;


    } // end of switch statement

    };

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        the_food.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM):

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent

You are not supplying a `Uri` with a `content` scheme. Instead, you are supplying a `Bitmap`. Probably Gmail is crashing because it is trying to cast a `Bitmap` to a `Uri`.